# Delphi button in the iOS or Android lock screen

Tags: android, ios, delphi, background, lockscreen

is there a way to insert in the lock screen a simple button.
It is for a Web radio and I want the user to be able to close the application that is in the background.
I need it for Android and iOS. Rad Studio 10.4.1 (Sydney).

Suggestions?